# I have a question about decimal division in Java

Tags: java, decimal

I used Java to get the ratio and added it all, but I didn't get 1.

| A | B | C | D | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.3 | 0.33 | 0.333 | 0.3333 | 1.2963 |
| 0.231427910205971 | 0.254570701226568 | 0.256884980328628 | 0.257116408238834 | 1 |

In Google Spreadsheet, if you find the ratio and add it all up, you get 1.

However, in Java, no matter which rounding mode is selected, 1 does not come out when all the ratios are added.

How does Google Spreadsheet perform Bigdecimal operations?

How can I add all the ratios and get 1 in Java?

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class TestTest {

    @Test
    public void testI() {
        RatioTest a = new RatioTest("0.3");
        RatioTest b = new RatioTest("0.33");
        RatioTest c = new RatioTest("0.333");
        RatioTest d = new RatioTest("0.3333");

        BigDecimal sum = a.getAmount().add(b.getAmount()).add(c.getAmount()).add(d.getAmount());
        System.out.println("sum : " + sum);
        a.setRatio(a.amount.divide(sum, 15, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
        b.setRatio(b.amount.divide(sum, 15, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
        c.setRatio(c.amount.divide(sum, 15, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
        d.setRatio(d.amount.divide(sum, 15, RoundingMode.FLOOR));

        System.out.println("a : " + a);
        System.out.println("b : " + b);
        System.out.println("c : " + c);
        System.out.println("d : " + d);
        System.out.println("ratio sum : " + a.getRatio().add(b.getRatio()).add(c.getRatio()).add(d.getRatio()));
    }

    private static class RatioTest {
        private BigDecimal amount;
        private BigDecimal ratio;

        public RatioTest(String amount) {
            this.amount = new BigDecimal(amount);
        }

        public BigDecimal getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public BigDecimal getRatio() {
            return ratio;
        }

        public void setRatio(BigDecimal ratio) {
            this.ratio = ratio;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "RatioTest{" +
                    "amount=" + amount +
                    ", ratio=" + ratio +
                    '}';
        }
    }

}
```

`a.amount.divide(sum, 15, RoundingMode.FLOOR)`
No matter which RoundingMode is used, the sum does not equal 1.

Comment: You did not include any java code. 'I divided some stuff and used BigDecimal' is about all the detail you provided. That's not enough to help you.

Comment: I added the code as per your advice.

Comment: This prints "0.999999999999997" which is precisely what you programmed. I'm not sure why you're confused: Your divide operation specifies: Round to 15 digits, and round down. No wonder then, the 15th digit is a 7 instead of a 10. I guess my question is: Why does this answer surprise you?

Comment: As far as 'how do I get a perfect 1.0 result' is concerned: You can't, no non-magical computer could do that here, given the constraints of decimal-based math operations (`BigDecimal` is decimal based, as in, base 10). A ratio-based system could do it (you'd need to look into third party java libraries). The more usual strategy is to round-as-you-output. Use e.g. `String.format("%.10f", amount)` and you'll get 1.0, because 0.999999999999997 rounded so that it doesn't take more than 10 digits after the comma, is 1.0.

Comment: I want to make a program like Google Spreadsheet in Java, which is the core of my question. 
In Google Spreadsheet, when you add up all the results, you get 1. 
Anyway thanks for the reply.

Comment: Print your cells using a rounding algorithm.